# Returning a string which contains some JSON object from ServiceStack

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I have the following DTO:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Info { get; set; }
}
```

The *Info* element contains some serialized JSON object which can be of multiple different types.
In my service function, I return this DTO using `return x.ConvertTo<MyDTO>()`

My problem is, that, since ServiceStack is not aware that *Info* holds a JSON, the special characters (quotation marks) of *Info* are escaped.

So I get

```
{"Id":15,"Info":"[\"Test1\",\"Test2\",\"Test3\"]"}
```

from the service, but what I would like to get is actually

```
{"Id":15,"Info":["Test1","Test2","Test3"]}
```

Is there some way, to tell ServiceStack that *Info* holds JSON data and thus prevent it from escaping the string and instead inserting the JSON value directly into the response?

P.S.: My question is not a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317225), which is concerned with forcing the default DTO encoding of a service to JSON, while my problem deals with how the JSON encoding happens for certain types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ServiceStack default format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317225/servicestack-default-format)

Comment: @PranavPatel My question is not a duplicate of that question. It is concerned with forcing the default DTO encoding of a service to JSON, while my problem deals with how the JSON encoding happens for certain types.

Comment: Maybe this helps? ► https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729811/json-net-unexpected-characters-when-serializing-my-entities-entity-framew

Comment: @Fran The default behaviour of the serialization process is understandable, you do no want just any quotation marks in a string to mess up your JSON types.
But in this case, since I know my string is a valid JSON (since I encoded it myself when storing it in a database), I would like to integrate it seamlessly, into the JSON encoded return DTO so that the client can use it right away without having to do any derserialization duties.

Comment: @mat what is expected is not valid JSON. This is not valid JSON `{"Id":15,"Info":"{["Test1","Test2","Test3"]}"}`. What you actually get is correct as Info is a string so thus it is escaped.

Comment: @Nkosi You are correct, thank you. I updated my question and fixed the examples.

Comment: @mat in the snippet `x.ConvertTo<MyDTO>()`, is `x` a JSON string or an other object type?

Comment: `x` is my database object from OrmLite, which has the same fields (*int Id* and *string Info*) as MyDTO, plus some extra fields.

Comment: @mat, I was thinking of something with generics like `public class MyDTO<T> {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public T Info { get; set; }
    }`
 but still working out how to do the conversion based on the source.

Comment: @Nkosi That won't work. Info can basically be encoded from any type. The decoding and interpretation of the values are done solely in the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

using composition you can interpret the `Info` property of `MyDTO`

```
public class MyDTO<T> : MyDTO {

    public MyDTO(MyDTO dto) {
        this.Id = dto.Id;
        this.Info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(dto.Info);
    }

    public new T Info { get; set; }
}
```

that way the JSON value in Info can be normalized before returning it to be serialized.

For example

```
var dto = x.ConvertTo<MyDTO>();
return new MyDTO<dynamic>(dto);
```

If `dto.Info` was a JSON array of strings would allow the array to be serialized as desired in the OP

```
var dto = new MyDTO {
    Id = 15,
    Info = "[\"Test1\",\"Test2\",\"Test3\"]"
}
```

would produce

```
{"Id":15,"Info":"[\"Test1\",\"Test2\",\"Test3\"]"}
```

where as

```
new MyDTO<dynamic>(dto);
```

would produce

```
{"Id":15,"Info":["Test1","Test2","Test3"]}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. ServiceStack can't return a dynamic interface from a service.

Comment: Play around with other return types. This was just meant as an example that it is possible. I ran this through some unit tests and it serialized just like I said.

Comment: @mat Returning JSON in a string is always escaped as a JSON string, irrespective if it contains valid JSON or not. This answer to deserialize it into a generic type is the right one although you shouldn't put any logic in DTOs, (I prefer to use an extension method instead). The other option is to return an `object` although that [should be heavily discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785).

Answer (score 2):

My co-workers and I faced a similar problem, and [with the help of Demis Bellot](https://twitter.com/demisbellot/status/1135662388349460481) we were able to arrive at a solution that, if translated to the code in the OP, would look like this:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> Info { get; set; }
}
```

When we populate the DTO, we use `JSON.parse` like this:

```
var json = (Dictionary<string, object>)JSON.parse(rawJsonString);
return new MyDTO
{
    Id = 42,
    Info = json
};
```

Our raw JSON string was a JSON *object*. In the OP, it looks like the raw JSON string may, instead, be an array, in which case [it looks as though](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#js-utils) the appropriate property type might be `List<object>`.

`JSON.parse` can be found in [ServiceStack.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Common).