# Change ServiceStack default format to JSON, but keep HTML format for SwaggerUI

Tags: json, servicestack, swagger-ui

Essentially, I want all of my responses returned in JSON by default, searched for an answer and stumbled upon this discussion: [ServiceStack default format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317225/servicestack-default-format)

What I tried:

1. Setting DefaultContentType to JSON and disabling Feature.Html --> works for responses, but breaks SwaggerUI (error on page render)
2. Only setting DefaultContentType to JSON --> doesn't break SwaggerUI, but making requests to my services from browser returns HTML (which makes sense because browsers usually the Accept header to receive html or xml, but I want to default to JSON)

That said, is there any way to *only* (and safely) enable Feature.Html for SwaggerUI? Maybe using PreRequestFilters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is removing the HTML Format essentially removes HTML ContentType from consideration, but I've changed it to preserve the Content Type if the Service returns a raw HTML string in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/f1076051be576397f025fde87e3b4fe7b7b63da6) where the Swagger UI can return HTML pages even if the HTML Format is disabled.

This change is available from v5.4.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

An alternative is to leave the HTML Format enabled but use a request filter to change the Content Type to JSON where it's HTML for all Requests you want to do this for, e.g:

```
PreRequestFilters.Add((req, res) => {
    if (req.ResponseContentType.Matches(MimeTypes.Html) && !req.PathInfo.StartsWith("/swagger-ui"))
        req.ResponseContentType = MimeTypes.Json;
});
```